# Index/match not capturing all data

Tags: excel

I am trying to use INDEX/MATCH to capture data with multiple criteria from one range (which will be located in worksheet1) to a cell in worksheet 2. Here is the formula and cells I am working with:

=INDEX($W$5:$W$86,MATCH(1,($B$14=P5:P86)*($E$4=S5:S86),0))

[image]

The formula is in cell E14 but the value is incorrect. It should be calculating cells W82 and W86 (448). I have tried a modified version of the formula to include the SUM, but I get #VALUE or #SPILL error messages. What am I not doing correctly? Or is INDEX/MATCH not the way to go for what I am trying to achieve here?

I also plan to convert this into VBA for which I am sure I will be asking some questions later (pending research)...lo

Comment: I think you should seperate our your individual equations to seperate columns, it'll make it easier to debug. Also I imagine it's your match statement which is causing the issue. You probably have multiple rows which when timed together have the same result. I think this is the issue ($B$14=P5:P86)*($E$4=S5:S86)

Comment: Quick question, why VBA. I'd recommend using the new javascript / typescript plugins or use power query to do a lot of this. Both are far superior

Comment: Your current formula returns a match and you should lock the references like this: `=INDEX($W$5:$W$86,MATCH(1,($B14=$P$5:$P$86)*(E$4=$S$5:$S$86),0))`. What you're looking for is a sum: `=SUMPRODUCT($W$5:$W$86,($P$5:$P$86=$B14)*($S$5:$S$86=E$4))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And what about traditional `SUMIFS`?

```
=SUMIFS($W$5:$W$86,$P$5:$P$86,$B$14,$S$5:$S$86,$E$4)
```

Comment: Your formula doesn't work correctly if you copy it to another cell. You need to properly lock the criteria cell references (`E4` and `B14`): one needs only the columns locked and the other the rows. See my comment above.

Comment: It is only an example based on the formula given by OP. Of course references should be tailored as needed.

Comment: @VBasic2008 I did lock the referencing cells in my example.

Comment: @MGonet I had just started looking at the SUMIFS when I checked back here. Thank you for the assist. Now my real dilemma is putting this in VBA where the data will have varying range each day.